# How to two-way bind my own RxJS Subject to an [(ngModel)]?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-ngmodel, rxjs5

Is there a short and simple way to pass an RxJS [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html) or [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html) to an an Angular 2 directive for two-way binding? The long way to do it would be as follows:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <input type="text" [ngModel]="subject | async" (ngModelChange)="subject.next($event)" />
    `
})
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="subject" />
    `
})
```

I believe the `async` pipe is only one-way, so that's not enough. Does Angular 2 provide a short and simple way to do this? Angular 2 uses RxJS too, so I expected there to be some inherent compatibility.

Could I perhaps create a new `ngModel`-like directive to make this possible?

Comment: What do you expect to happen when the value of the input changes? `Subject` is one-way. `[ngModel]="subject | async" (ngModelChange)="subject.next($event)"` might work

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer [`Subject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Subject.js~Subject.html) is two-way, though. It's both an [`Observer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html) and an [`Observable`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html). I'm also fine with this always being a [`BehaviorSubject`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/BehaviorSubject.js~BehaviorSubject.html), if it helps (because that has a method to access the current value).

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Afraid not. I guess I stopped caring at some point. :-)

Comment: Though now that I think about it, a custom attribute-based directive could probably be created for this.

Comment: Afaik there is no better way to bind it to `Subject`. I tried to create such directive but it looks its not possible to add `ngModel` directive to my directive's host.

Comment: I don't think it's doable. However [there was an attempt](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248) by the angular team to solve part of this issue.

Answer (score 28):

This is a simple solution, as you said in your question. I think there's nothing simpler than what you already provided.

```
<input type="text" 
       [ngModel]="subject | async"
       (ngModelChange)="subject.next($event)" />
```

Answer (score 10):

A possible solution is a sublcass of BehaviorSubject:

```
class ModelSubject<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {

    constructor(initialValue: T) {
        super(initialValue);
    }

    set model(value: T) {
        this.next(value);
    }

    get model(): T {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

Component-Class:

```
name = new ModelSubject<string>('');
```

Component-Template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="name.model">
```

Comment: this works great!

Comment: This may work for some use-cases but it entirely entirely removes the async pipe and defeats the point of using continuous Observables on the template as well.

Comment: Can you update your examples in the code sections of your answer? It seems like `name =` and `firstName.model` are not the same variable names. is `name` supposed to match `firstName`?

Comment: @activedecay You're right. Done....

Answer (score 5):

I've started looking into something like this to integrate form controls with my library [ng-app-state](https://github.com/simontonsoftware/ng-app-state). If you are the type who enjoys making very generic, library-like code then read on. But beware, this is long! In the end you should be able to use this in your templates:

```
<input [subjectModel]="subject">
```

I have made a proof-of-concept for the first half of this answer, and the second half I believe is correct, but be warned that none of actual code written in this answer is tested. I'm sorry, but that's the best I have to offer right now. :)

You can write your own directive called `subjectModel` to connect a subject to a form component. Following are the essential parts, minus things like cleanup. It relies on the [`ControlValueAccessor`](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) interface, so Angular includes the necessary adapters to hook this up to all the standard HTML form elements, **and** it will work with any custom form controls you find in the wild, as long as they use `ControlValueAccessor` (which is the recommended practice).

```
@Directive({ selector: '[subjectModel]' })
export class SubjectModelDirective {
    private valueAccesor: ControlValueAccessor;

    constructor(
        @Self() @Inject(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR)
        valueAccessors: ControlValueAccessor[],
    ) {
        this.valueAccessor = valueAccessors[0]; // <- this can be fancier
    }

    @Input() set subjectModel(subject: Subject) {
        // <-- cleanup here if this was already set before
        subject.subscribe((newValue) => {
            // <-- skip if this is already the value
            this.valueAccessor.writeValue(newValue);
        });
        this.valueAccessor.registerOnChange((newValue) => {
            subject.next(newValue);
        });
    }
}
```

We could stop here, and you'll be able to write this in your templates:

```
<input [subjectModel]="subject" [ngDefaultControl]>
```

That extra [`[ngDefaultControl]`](https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor) exists to manually cause angular to provide the needed `ControlValueAccessor` to our directive. Other kinds of inputs (like radio buttons and selects) would need a different extra directive. This is because Angular does not automatically attached value accessors to every form component, only those that also have an `ngModel`, `formControl`, or `formControlName`.

If you want to go the extra mile to eliminate the need for those extra directives, you'll have to essentially copy them into your code, but modify their selectors to activate for your new `subjectModel`. This is the totally untested part, but I believe you could do this:

```
// This is copy-paste-tweaked from
// https://angular.io/api/forms/DefaultValueAccessor
@Directive({
    selector: 'input:not([type=checkbox])[subjectModel],textarea[subjectModel]',
    host: {
        '(input)': '_handleInput($event.target.value)',
        '(blur)': 'onTouched()',
        '(compositionstart)': '_compositionStart()',
        '(compositionend)': '_compositionEnd($event.target.value)'
    },
    providers: [DEFAULT_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class DefaultSubjectModelValueAccessor extends DefaultValueAccessor {}
```

Credit for my understanding of this goes to [ngrx-forms](https://github.com/MrWolfZ/ngrx-forms), which employes this technique.

Comment: Looks interesting. Was this solution available back when I first asked the question? --- I'm afraid I won't have time to verify this. I use React in my new job, and my mind really isn't in Angular space right now. --- If someone else could verify, I'd be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure when this would have become possible.

Answer (score 5):

> 'If the mountain will not come to Muhammad, then Muhammad must go to the mountain'

Lets approach this from RxJS side instead of the NgModel side.

This solution limits us to only use `BehaviorSubject`'s but I think this is a fair trade for having such an easy solution.

Slap this piece of code into your polyfills.ts. This enables you to bind the `.value` of a `BehaviorSubject` to an `ngModel`

```js
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

Object.defineProperty(BehaviorSubject.prototype, 'value', {
    set: function(v) {
        return this.next(v);
    }
});
```

And just use it like this.

```html
<ng5-slider [(value)]="fooBehaviorSubject.value" ...
```

Comment: Adding this to `polyfills.ts` does the trick in development builds. This solution gives a build error (`Attempt to assign to const or readonly variable`) in production, because `value` property is still seen as readonly by the compiler. I had to use Mario's solution.

Comment: who/what is muhamamannad? i don't understand the quote here

Answer (score 2):

I tried this and it worked

```
<div>
    <input
        #searchInput
        type="search"
        [ngModel]="searchTerm | async"
        (ngModelChange)="searchTerm.next(searchInput.value)"
    />
    {{ searchTerm | async }}
</div>
```

[image]

I'm not sure it this is breaking any rules and if it's buggy or hacky but seems to work for me. I wish Angular had a built it subject directive like they do with forms.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can think of is to use a FormControl:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
    template: '<input [formControl]="control">'
})
class MyComponent {
    control = new FormControl('');
    constructor(){
        this.control.valueChanges.subscribe(()=> console.log('tada'))
    }
}
```