# Filtering an observable array into another observable array (of another type) by an observable property of the items

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding, rxjs

As the title probably doesn't explain to well what I am doing, I'll give a small example:

A REST api returns a list of objects. For each of them, a checkbox should be displayed and the selected values used for further processing. However, the api might be called multiple times (to refresh the data), so I am dealing with Observables and the result (i.e. the selected objects) should also be available as an Observable.

[I have created a simple Plunker to illustrate this](https://plnkr.co/edit/vNpDk0j9ZRlxM3SOK8io): I receive an observable in my Component with an array of objects (here just strings to simplify):

```
var observable = Observable.of(["Hello", "World"]);
```

Based on this, I create objects of type `Item` while store the object and the information whether they are checked or not (as an Observable/BehaviorSubject):

```
this.items$ = observable.map(arr => arr.map(s => new Item(s)))
//...
class Item {
   public readonly isChecked$ : BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);

   constructor(public readonly value : string) { }
}
```

Then, I display them using the solution from [How to two-way bind my own RxJS Subject to an [(ngModel)]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38662155/how-to-two-way-bind-my-own-rxjs-subject-to-an-ngmodel) :

```
<li *ngFor="let item of items$ | async as items" >
   <input id="cb-{{item.value}}" type="checkbox" [ngModel]="item.isChecked$ | async" (ngModelChange)="item.isChecked$.next($event)"  />
   <label for="cb-{{item.value}}">{{item.value}}</label>
</li>
```

However, I now have real problems to get an `Observable<string[]>` containing the selected values. Basically, I have an `Observable<Item[]>` and I need to:

1. Access the observables of the array items (item.isSelected$)
2. Filter based on their value
3. **Convert the result back to an Observable, i.e. collect the values (at one time) in an array and return it as an Observable**

Number three is what I was not able to achieve: As soon as I `flatMap` the array for example, there seems to be "no way back" to create an array again - I do not want to end up with an `Observable<string>` (notifying me when a new item is checked), but with an `Observable<string[]>` which is raised each time the set of the selected items changes.

The best I could come up with is the code in the plunker (which relies on subscribe + manually inserting the values into a second array):

```
this.items$
    .switchMap(items => items.map(item => item.isChecked$.map(isChecked => ({ checked: isChecked, value: item.value}))))
    .mergeAll()
    .subscribe(o => {
        var selected = this._selectedItems.slice(0);
        if (o.checked)
            selected.push(o.value);
        else {
            var index = selected.indexOf(o.value);
            selected.splice(index, 1);
        }

        this._selectedItems = selected;
        this._selectedItems$.next(this._selectedItems);
    });
```

Is there a more elegant function in rxjs allowing me to achieve this (without the need for the second array)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push values into another observable, you should use a `Subject`. A `Subject` acts as both an observer and an observable.

So your filter can push values into the new observable by using the `next()` method, something like this

```
mySubject.next(val)
```

Another part of your code can subscribe to this subject, and react accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the response. My code is already using a BehaviorSubject to store the isChecked value of the item. Also, my selectedItems is one. So you are basically describing what I am doing now. What I want to do is to get the Observable of selected items in a truly reactive way, i.e. without doing a subscribe and manually maintaining the array (which then gets written into the BehaviorSubject).

Answer (score 0):

Consider keeping a `BehaviorSubject` up to date with your item list, then you can map your checkbox events to the states of all your items.

```
const item_subject$ = new BehaviorSubject([]); // BehaviorSubject<Item[]>
items$.scan((acc, item) => acc.push(item), [])
      .subscribe(item_subject$);

const checked_subject$ = new Subject(); // Subject<string[]>
items$.subscribe(item =>
  item.isChecked$.subscribe(_ => 
    checked_subject.next(
      item_subject$.getValue()
                   .filter(inner_item => inner_item.isChecked$.getValue())
                   .map(inner_item => inner_item.value)
    )
  )
);
```

**Timing:**

`checked_subject$` should never have false positives thanks to the happens-before of `isChecked$` updating its value to `isChecked$` emitting to its subscribers. The only racey part might be the assumed happens-before of `scan` in line 2 pushing a new item into the `item_subject` vs. that item changing state. Not a realistic concern I imagine, since users would have to click instantly when the new items renders.

Answer (score 0):

for that kind of problems I use [Angular Material CDK Collection](https://material.angular.io/cdk/collections/overview)

You can select or deselect items and subscribe to the model to get it in reactive way.

```
const model = new SelectionModel(
  true,   // multiple selection or not
  [2,1,3] // initial selected values
);

// select a value
model.select(4);
console.log(model.selected.length) //->  4

// deselect a value
model.deselect(4);
console.log(model.selected.length) //->  3

// toggle a value
model.toggle(4);
console.log(model.selected.length) //->  4

// check for selection
console.log(model.isSelected(4)) //-> true

// sort the selections
console.log(model.sort()) //-> [1,2,3,4]

// listen for changes
model.changed.subscribe(s => console.log(s));
```